# Node / Mysql dates issues

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm using `mysql2` and have this issue:

mysql column type is `DATE`, the value is shown as `2005-02-20` when I run a query. But, when I get to my app in react, I got this `2005-02-20T00:00:00.000Z`.

The problem with this is since I'm on **-03:00GMT** when I check on screen I get `2005-02-19`.

Is there any option that it could be done with some library? or may be some configuration so it retrieves as `yyyy-mm-dd` **only**?

sql call:

```
const getPersona  = ( personaID ) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const qry = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE persona_id = ?"
    conn.query(qry, personaID, (err, rows) => {
      if(err) return reject(err)
      resolve(rows[0])
    })
  }) ;
}
```

react code:

```
new Date(this.props.persona.birthdate)
```

Comment: What code are you using to get the date from MySQL to React? Stack Overflow answerers generally want to see what you've done to solve the problem yourself, including research and attempts.

Comment: use https://date-fns.org/ with React